# Can we upload and download files from AWS EFS using Java and Spring Boot through an API?

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-efs

Can we use Java and [Spring Boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework#Spring_Boot) to upload files through an API?

I tried to get the details of integration of [EFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_File_System) with Spring Boot from the AWS website, but without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any direct way to upload/download files to AWS EFS from the local system. You need to mount the EFS file system locally using `amazon-efs-utils` package and then perform normal file operations using Java file I/O.

More details regarding mounting an EFS file system are here:

1. *[Mounting EFS file systems](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mounting-fs.html)*
2. *[Manually installing the Amazon EFS client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/installing-amazon-efs-utils.html)*

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either [AWS Transfer family](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/transfer/AWSTransferClient.html) or [AWS Data sync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/datasync/AWSDataSyncClient.html).

Currently, Spring cloud AWS does not have support for EFS, but it has it for [S3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_S3). See *[9.3. Downloading files](https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/current/reference/html/index.html#downloading-files)*.